# What is this valve for?

Tags: plumbing, valve

[image]

It's located on the first floor closet of a two story home build in late 1990.

I takes 5 turns to completely open and close and can't hear anything flowing when turned.

It does not shutoff water to the house, tested.

Comment: For you to have a need to ask the question.  It can be for almost anything, and about the only way to find out is to check(probably opening up the wall) what pipes go near there and where there go.  Might be a water line no longer used.

Comment: @crip659 is right, and that could be *the* answer. For safety's sake, close it when you're done messing around.

Comment: Oh, but did you check your outside hose bibs?

Comment: What is on the other side of that wall?

Comment: Got an outside spigot?

Answer (score 1):

Look outside. Is there a hose connection somewhere near this on the outside of the house? Would be *very* typical of a "shut off the hose supply in winter" valve (so proper use is shut this valve, open the hose valve to drain the pipe between this and the hose valve.)

Slight possibility (uncommon, and generally *much* better labeled and painted red if present) would be if your house has sprinklers.

Answer (score 1):

**Cold water**

Seriously. The convention is blue for cold, red for hot. That's all we can tell from looking at the valve. You have to find what stops working, or what starts leaking, to know what it controls:

- Entire house (already ruled out)
- Outside hose connection (as suggested in comments; quite common to have an indoor shutoff for the winter)
- Cold water to a section of the house (e.g., I have water pipes in two areas - kitchen/laundry and bathrooms - it wouldn't be unreasonable to have a shutoff for one side of the house).
- Cold water to one fixture (toilet, sink, tub/shower) or appliance (water heater, washing machine). Usually this will be very close to the fixture or appliance, but anything is possible.